# How do I call multiple custom alert views on a UIButton tap from a single UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewControllerA and two custom alerts and I'm calling the first custom alert on the buttonclick action of the ViewControllerA.

In first custom alert I'm having a text field and a button.

When I click on the button action of first custom alert , I want to open the second custom alert and both alerts I want show on ViewControllerA.

`The expected result is to show both the custom alerts on the single ViewControllerA`

Please help me out to solve this problem

```
class ViewControllerA : UIViewController{
@IBAction func ViewControllerAButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {  
        FirstCustomalert.instance.ShowAlert()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
class FirstCustomAlert : UIView{
 @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
    static let instance = FirstCustomAlert()
    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstCustomAlert", owner: self, options: nil)

        CommonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func CommonInit(){

        alertView.frame = CGRect(x: center.x, y: center.y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        ParentView.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleHeight , .flexibleWidth ]
    }
    func ShowAlert(){
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(ParentView)
    }
    @IBAction func SubmitBittonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        SecondCustomAlert.instances.ShowAlerts()
    }
}
```

```
class SecondCustomAlert :  UIView{
 @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!
    static let instances = SecondCustomAlert()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
 Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SecondCustomAlert", owner: self, options: nil)
    }
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func CommonInit(){
        parentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        parentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth , .flexibleHeight ]
    }
    func ShowAlerts(){

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(parentView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there are a number of things you need to change:

1. Naming convention:

Your methods should be named with lowerCamelCase and only classes and objects should be CamelCase.

2. You are building a custom alert to be displayed from anywhere in the app. Since you are already using .xib, I would suggest that you refactor your alert into a `ViewController` and use `present(viewController: animated:)` with `presentationStyle` of `.overCurrentContext`. You can get the `topViewController` on the `keyWindow` which you have and call the `present` function. Then in your `AlertViewController` you can do separate animations to display the second view of the alert upon button click.

What you are trying to do now is put too much logic into a `UIView`, which is not best practise and it isn't very scalable. Plus it looks messy. You are trying to achieve something relatively simply but the current approach already creates 2 customs views and you are already encountering callback issues.

ADD:

```
class ViewControllerA : UIViewController{
@IBAction func ViewControllerAButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {  
        let customAlert = CustomAlertViewController()
        customAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(customAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: But Sir , is it possible to display both the custom alert view controllers on ViewControllerA ????

Comment: I changed .xib to viewcontroller but the expected result is to show both the view controllers on the single ViewControllerA

Comment: You can present your custom AlertViewController from ViewControllerA:

Comment: Sir if possible then can you share me a link for the reference...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
              let dest = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "custom") as!CustomAlertViewController
              dest.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext                          self.present(dest, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: This worked for me... As I added your code its showing me an error ......